# How do I remove TeamViewers notification that it is still running in the background?

Tags: wine, notification, teamviewer

There seems to be a bug with the current TeamViewer implementation on Linux where it shows a Windows-looking "balloon" type notification informing the user that TeamViewer is still running in the background. To disable this notification, the user is encouraged to click the notification, but this does not work.

As clicking the notification does not work, how do you make TeamViewer no longer display the message, seemingly triggered by full screen applications?

Answer (score 9):

According to [this forum thread on Linux Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=152105&p=792705), there is a value called `ShowTaskbarInfoOnMinimize` that TeamViewer stores in the Windows registry. However, the TeamViewer implementation in Linux does not use Wine's registry, so the modification needs to be done to the following file (as per the comment below, **shut down TeamViewer before editing this file**):

`~/.config/teamviewer9/config/client.conf`

Add the following line to the end of the file:

`[int32] ShowTaskbarInfoOnMinimize = 0`

...and start TeamViewer back up.

The notification should no longer appear.

**edit**: If this solution does not work for you, please open up the file again and verify that the value is actually set to zero. For me, it actually reset back to 1 and had to be corrected and saved, and the next time TeamViewer started up it worked. Might have been me that did something wrong, but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: I think it got reset back to 1 because teamviewer was running, and it writes it's config on exit, so it's better to close teamviewer before editing the file.