# disable Teamviewer notification

Tags: 12.04, notification, teamviewer

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I am annoyed by Teamviewer notification when I minimize Teamviewer window. I depict as figure below

[image]

The message says that "click here to disable" but the fact it doesn't. I search in option menu but the these options may not be related to. I wonder if there is anyway to disable notification like that ones?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is solved [following this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/419807). I follow this, and the notification was disabled.